# How to change prefix locale in blade laravel?

Tags: laravel, locale, laravel-blade

I have middleware

```
    public static function getLocale()
    {
        $mainLanguage = config('translatable.locale');
        $languages = config('translatable.locales');
        $uri = Request::path();
        $segmentsURI = explode('/',$uri);
        if (!empty($segmentsURI[0]) && in_array($segmentsURI[0], $languages)) {

            return $segmentsURI[0];

        } else {
            return  $mainLanguage;
        }
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $locale = self::getLocale();
        if($locale) {
            App::setLocale($locale);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

This is my routes/web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['localize'], 
'prefix' => App\Http\Middleware\LocaleMiddleware::getLocale()], function () {
...routes...
});
```

This is my header.blade, where I want to change the language of my dropdown choice

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
     @foreach(config('translatable.locales') as $locale)
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{strtoupper($locale)}}</a>
     @endforeach
</div>
```

My header is connected to layout and is available on all pages.
I want my routes to look like this (example):
.../en/news
.../en/news/1

> What should I write in `a href` so that I can change the language?
>   I tried `{{$locale . "/" . Request::segment(2)}}`
>   but i get .../es/news/ru/news

Comment: if the locale was a route parameter you could generate urls to the routes easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue. I added function in route

```
Route::get('setlocale/{lang}', function ($lang) {

        $referer = Redirect::back()->getTargetUrl();
        $parse_url = parse_url($referer, PHP_URL_PATH);
        $segments = explode('/', $parse_url);
        if (in_array($segments[1], App\Http\Middleware\LocaleMiddleware::$languages)) {

            unset($segments[1]);
        }
        if ($lang != App\Http\Middleware\LocaleMiddleware::$mainLanguage){
            array_splice($segments, 1, 0, $lang);
        }
        $url = Request::root().implode("/", $segments);
        if(parse_url($referer, PHP_URL_QUERY)){
            $url = $url.'?'. parse_url($referer, PHP_URL_QUERY);
        }
        return redirect($url);

    })->name('setlocale');
```